C# string sorting doesn't work as expected. What's the problem?
given an array of strings, and I want to sort it, the code as follows
string[] s = ["=:rr", "2:yy", "=:hh"];
Array.Sort(s);
foreach (var item in s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

my expected result:
2:yy
=:hh
=:rr

the actual result:
=:hh
=:rr
2:yy

From what I understand, strings are sorted based on the Unicode value of each character. '2' has a Unicode value of 50, and '=' has a Unicode value of 61. So why isn't the result as expected?

What is your CurrentCulture?

"strings are sorted based on the Unicode value of each character" - Not by default, no. Use StringComparer.Ordinal for that.

By default strings are ordered using the current culture's sorting rules. You can specify different rules by passing a different comparer as an argument

It looks like the actual result would be the US English result if sorted by spelling

Although not the case here, I think it's worth pointing out that sometimes you have to store the result of a method back to the entity, e.g. s = s.func(); not just s.func()

You can add the comparer like this: Array.Sort(s, StringComparer.Ordinal).


From what I understand, strings are sorted based on the Unicode value of each character.

Not by default, from Collation, sorting, and string comparison

Each language has a set or sets of rules for how language strings should be sorted or "collated" into an ordered list. Collation is the term for how the sorting order of strings of characters is determined. This concept is important to globalization when it comes to the alphabetic order of each language.

By default a culture sensitive comparer will be used. If you want a byte comparison , see StringComparer.Ordinal
